# View javadoc locally with localhost:8080

Tags: java, maven, javadoc

I am currently documenting a Java Spring API that I have been writing and I want to use javadocs.
We deploy our API using Docker and DroneCI.
I know that I can generate the javadocs with `mvn javadoc:javadoc` and the jar with `mvn javadoc:jar`.
However I have been unable to run this jar using

```
java -jar target/my-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
```

no main manifest attribute, in target/seba-platform-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar

Is it possible to run the javadoc jar locally to view the javadocs using `http://localhost:8080/` ?

Comment: Why don't you just open index.html in your browser, why do you need to run it on a local server?

Comment: Because I want to deploy it to our kubernetes cluster and would like to avoid having to extract the HTML every time I deploy. Is there not a way to "run" the jar? So that i can access the javadocs in the same way i access the api endpoints

Comment: how would "run the jar" deploy it to your kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 0):

just extract your javadoc jar

```
jar -xvf my-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
```

and open the html directly with browser (chrome for example)

Comment: Thanks for this. However, I want to deploy it to our kubernetes cluster and would like to avoid having to extract the HTML every time I deploy. Is there not a way to "run" the jar? So that i can access the javadocs in the same way i access the api endpoints